# How to set a double with Java Annotations

Tags: java-annotations

I am writing a custom module for use with Tridiums Niagara Framework version 4.3 and the defaultValue I am trying to set is giving the following error:

> 'class' or 'interface' expected error.

I've tried several different ways to set this and the error remains. I have tried starting from scratch and get the same error.

```
package com.lgelectronics.lge;

import javax.baja.nre.annotations.Facet;
import javax.baja.nre.annotations.NiagaraProperty;
import javax.baja.nre.annotations.NiagaraType;
import javax.baja.sys.*;

@NiagaraType

@NiagaraProperty
    (
            name = "Schedule",
            type = "Baja:Boolean",
            flags = Flags.SUMMARY,
            defaultValue = "False"
    )
@NiagaraProperty
    (
            name = "OccupiedCoolingSetPoint",
            type = "Baja:Double",
            flags = Flags.SUMMARY,
            facets=
                    {
@Facet(name = "BFacets.UNITS", value = "BUnit.getUnit(\"fahrenheit\")"),
@Facet(name = "BFacets.PRECISION", value = "BInteger.make(1)"),
@Facet(name = "BFacets.MIN", value = "BDouble.make(0D)"),
@Facet(name = "BFacets.MAX", value = "BDouble.make(100D)")
                    },
          defaultValue = "BDouble.make(\"74.0\")"
    )
@NiagaraProperty
    (
            name = "UnOccupiedCoolingSetPoint",
            type = "Baja:Double",
            flags = Flags.SUMMARY,
            facets=
                    {
@Facet(name = "BFacets.UNITS", value = "BUnit.getUnit(\"fahrenheit\")"),
@Facet(name = "BFacets.PRECISION", value = "BInteger.make(1)"),
@Facet(name = "BFacets.MIN", value = "BDouble.make(0D)"),
@Facet(name = "BFacets.MAX", value = "BDouble.make(100D)")
                    },
      defaultValue = "BDouble.make(\"85.0\")"
    )
@NiagaraProperty
    (
            name = "OccupiedHeatingSetPoint",
            type = "Baja:Double",
            flags = Flags.SUMMARY,
            facets=
            {
@Facet(name = "BFacets.UNITS", value = "BUnit.getUnit(\"fahrenheit\")"),
@Facet(name = "BFacets.PRECISION", value = "BInteger.make(1)"),
@Facet(name = "BFacets.MIN", value = "BDouble.make(0D)"),
@Facet(name = "BFacets.MAX", value = "BDouble.make(100D)")
            },
            defaultValue = "BDouble.make(\"70.0\")"
    )
@NiagaraProperty
    (
            name = "UnOccupiedHeatingSetPoint",
            type = "Baja:Double",
            flags = Flags.SUMMARY,
            facets=
            {
@Facet(name = "BFacets.UNITS", value ="BUnit.getUnit(\"fahrenheit\")"),
@Facet(name = "BFacets.PRECISION", value = "BInteger.make(1)"),
@Facet(name = "BFacets.MIN", value = "BDouble.make(0D)"),
@Facet(name = "BFacets.MAX", value = "BDouble.make(100D)")
            },
            defaultValue = "BDouble.make(\"55.0\")"
    )
public class BSchedule extends BComponent {
}
```

I expect to not have a 'class' or 'interface' expected error on the defaultValue line.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is problem, you should use below syntax.

```
defaultValue = "BDouble.make(55.0)",
```

See full example,

```
@NiagaraProperty(
  name = "delayTime",
  type = "baja:Double",
  defaultValue = "BDouble.make(500)",
  facets = {
    @Facet(name = "BFacets.MIN", value = "BDouble.make(0)"),
    @Facet(name = "BFacets.MAX", value = "BDouble.make(2000)"),
    @Facet(name = "BFacets.UX_FIELD_EDITOR", value = "BString.make(\"midi:RangeSlider\")")
  }
)
```